# Function notation for $g(x(t),y(t),z(t))$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, notation

Say I have two functions
$$
f:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow\mathbb R, \quad f(x,y,z)\\
g:\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R, \quad g(x(t),y(t),z(t))
$$
Is there notation to distinguish between the functions, i.e. I want to say that for $g$ the variables $x$, $y$ and $z$ are functions of $t$, but I don't want to write $g(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ after $\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow\mathbb R$.

E.g. I want to write something like 
$$
f:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow\mathbb R\\
g:\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R
$$
And from this you know $f(x,y,z)$ but $g(x(t),y(t),z(t))$.

Hope the question is clear enough.
Thanks!

Comment: I believe that if $x,y,z$ are the functions of $t$ then $g$ is not defined on $\mathbb{R}^3$ but on the curve $C$ defined by $(x(t),y(t),z(t))$. I would write $g : C\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've written it is not entirely right.

g should be listed as mapping $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ in the way you've written it. This would be the ideal way to get it the way you want.

$\mathbf{r}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3 \ $ by $\ \mathbf{r}(t):=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$

$g : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R} \ $ by $ \ g(x,y,z) = $ whatever the function is

$ \\ $

You want the composition

$(g \ \circ \mathbf{r}) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

by $(g \ \circ \mathbf{r})(t) : = g(\mathbf{r}(t)) = g(x(t),y(t),z(t))$

Comment: Hi! So all I have to write are the functions $$\mathbf{r}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3 \\ g:\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow\mathbb R \\ h=(g\circ \mathbf r):\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$$ and just from this we know that $h(t)=(g \ \circ \mathbf{r})(t) = g(x(t),y(t),z(t))$?

Comment: @JDoeDoe I would also write $\mathbf{r}(t):=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$. Generally you use the $:A \to B$ notation to specify that the domain is A and the target is B, and then go on to explicitly define the function.

Answer (score 0):

For given functions $x(t),y(t),z(t)$ the function $g(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ only depends on $t \in \mathbb{R}$. So therefore your function $g$ is actually a function of only 1 variable, often called a "curve":
$$
g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R},t\to g(x(t),y(t),z(t))
$$
You can also define the function $h:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^3,t\to (x(t),y(t),z(t))$ and $\bar g:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R},(x,y,z) \to g(x,y,z)$ and then define $g=\bar g \circ h$ and look at the function that way.